# Make Kestrel serve file existing minified version of requested file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, bundle, minify, kestrel-http-server

What I want to achieve is the following.

When I recibe a request for a HTML, JS or CSS file, return its minified version. I minify when I publish, not dinamically.

Example:

1. Browser asks por /index.html
2. Server checks the extensions
3. Server checks if a index.min.html exists **on disk**
4. If exists, server returns index.min.html file, else index.html

*All in a single request*

I tried read about rewriting and file providers, but I didn't found a standard nor easy way to do this.

What should be the way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file will be gzip compressed in transit so is this necessary?

Comment: Is necesary to minify js or css? But I'm not asking about it's necessary or not, I just want to do it. And it's faster to parse by the engines.